# Python Optimizing Dict iteration

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a problem where I have a massive nested dictionary running and am looking to speed things up as the time it takes to go through the entire dictionary is about a week worth of processing time. Is there a faster way to iterating through something like the following (I'm not opposed to reworking the structure)? I need to iterate and not vectorize because the state for 2 depends on what happens in 1.

I'm nesting like what happens below where the structure basically is

```
def function(x):
    return 1

d = {'1': {'1a': 0, '1b': 0}, '2': {'2a': 0, '2b': 0, '2c': 0 } , '3': {'3a':0}}
s = {}
for outer_key, inner_dict in d.iteritems():
    for inner_key, inner_value in inner_dict.iteritems():
        s = function(inner_value)

    print(s)
```

Comment: Hard to tell what's taking so long without seeing a more real-life example. Are you iterating and comparing keys instead of using proper dict lookup?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "iterating through"? Your question as written is very unclear.

Comment: Please try to answer the following: How "massive", i.e. how many elements, and how many levels of nesting? How are you iterating through the dict? How do you determine the next key to use? Once you've decided on the next key, how do you access it? And what do you do once you've got it? Is it really the iterating that takes so long, or the computation you do on the elements?

Answer (score 1):

I'm making the assumption that by '*iterating*' you are meaning that you go through every single key in the outer dictionary, and then iterate through each key inside of the returned inner dictionaries.

When you interact with dictionaries in this manner, you're essentially treating them as linked lists (or in this case, as nested, ragged, lists). Iterating through a single list yields a runtime of `O(n)`, with nested lists ending up as `O(n * n) = O(n^2)`; this would be responsible for the large runtime you're experiencing if this structure is very large.

Additionally, you need to take into consideration the operations you're performing on each member of the children dictionaries. If you are performing some sort of processing that is going back through prior dictionaries and adjusting them, etc, your runtime could potentially be even worse (think nested `for` loop operations once you get to the child key).

I would question why you are needing to hit every single key within both hierarchies of dictionaries, since the primary advantage of using a dictionary is for situations where you know a specific key and need to find its associated value.

You mention that the nested dictionaries' states are contingent upon preceding dictionaries' states. Why not go with a tree of dictionaries (if you need constant-time lookup within the nested structures) instead of nested dictionaries? A tree would allow you to maintain the contingencies across children dictionaries, and traversing the tree could net you some runtime gains if you find that you don't actually need to hit every node.

Feel free to clarify what exactly you're doing throughout this process and I can update my answer to be more specific to your needs!

Comment: Exactly on iterating. The reason I am using dictionaries is because the throw everything under the sun structure that it lets me have a lot of flexibility for what goes in there. I wouldn't mind getting the dictionary then restructuring it into something faster.